# Entering the UK with an expired EU passport and a valid non-EU passport

Tags: passports, common-travel-area, evidence

I live in Ireland with a recently expired Italian passport and valid South African passport. I want to visit the UK and wonder if

1. the expired passport is proof of EU citizenship
2. I could get a free visa on my SA passport (as with EU family members)?

Comment: Have you got a permanent residence card or certificate from Ireland? If so, just use that. And of course you should renew your Italian passport (and keep the old one).

Comment: why you don't renew your Italian passport? it's the easier thing to do. Depending on your AIRE status you can also get an Italian ID Card that will allow you to enter UK

Comment: Thanks guys. I submitted my renewal application to the Italian consul a month ago but they can't confirm if it will be ready in time for my trip. I would like an ID card, but thought I have to be residing in Italy to be eligible.

Comment: @Pastabok did it work? What did you end up using? Perhaps you could put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are currently inside the Common Travel Area, your question is based solely on whether or not you get randomly picked for a challenge.  It's not very often that happens.

In the case that it does happen, your Italian passport will work as proof as long as the photo reasonably looks like you and your personal details dovetail with your other forms of ID such as driving permit, birth certificate or whatever else you can offer.

It's reasonable to expect that they are not going to be altogether happy about your travelling on an expired passport so you should pad in some extra time for them to land you in the UK.